# Running R script from crontab gives different results than from command line

Tags: r, bash, cron

I am using a machine that employs Ubuntu 10.04.4 (lucid) and R version 2.15.3.

I run this R script using `R CMD BATCH test.time.R` from the command line, and it works fine:

```
format(Sys.time(), " %H")
[1] " 15"

format(Sys.time(), " %H") >= 12
[1] TRUE
```

But when I run */1 * * * * R CMD BATCH test.time.R from crontab, it doesn't:

```
format(Sys.time(), " %H")
[1] " 15"

format(Sys.time(), " %H") >= 12
[1] FALSE
```

Any thoughts?

This is the only machine (out of four) where this is the case (other machines read it fine from crontab).

I'd appreciate any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu, `" 15" >= 12` gives me `TRUE`.  On Mac, I get `FALSE`.  Why do you have that space in there anyway?  For that matter, why are you comparing a string to a number?

Comment: Looks like that was it. Comparing the string to a number works in newer versions of Ubuntu but it needs to be numeric otherwise. The reason I had it that way is because it was working on all the other machines and, as a beginner, I just didn't think to change it.

Comment: @GSee, on Windows XP also `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare a string to a number if you don't have to.  If you removed the space from the format pattern (i.e. made it `"%H"` instead of `" %H"`), it should work.  However, you don't have to introduce strings in this case; you can get the hour as a number by converting to `POSIXlt` and extracting the `hour` component.  Try this:

```
as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())$hour > 12
```